# How to handle exceptions you want propagated up to the caller?

Tags: java

I'm a Pythonista moving into Java/Scala, and I am wondering how to handle the case where you want an exception to be thrown if it occurs.  Take the following toy example:

```
public class PersonSaver {
    private final File file;

    public PersonSaver(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void save(List<Person> people) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            output.writeObject(people);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In Python I would want this to throw an error if the file isn't found, and let the calling code handle the exception.  Is it convention just to re-throw the same exception?

Comment: just `throw;`. this will do.

Comment: either don't catch, or if you have to catch (due to a more generic exception), rethrow.

Comment: If the exception that occurs in your code is appropriate to the abstraction represented by your API, then don't catch it and allow it to fall out to the client code.  If the exception that occurs in your code is not appropriate to the abstraction, then the best practice is to catch it and rethrow the more apprpriate exception type.  This is especially true if your code makes use of checked exception types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your method throw those exceptions :

```
public class PersonSaver {
    private final File file;

    public PersonSaver(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void save(List<Person> people) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            output.writeObject(people);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle the exception you want to handle
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure you declare your method with the `throws` statement, or your compiler might not like it ;)

You can also go this way (let's call this a semi-exception-handling) :

```
public class PersonSaver {
    private final File file;

    public PersonSaver(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void save(List<Person> people) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            output.writeObject(people);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /*Some code to clear some data or to handle the 
              exception but still throw an exception higher*/
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you need to do something with the exception, you can just add the throws as noted in my response and safely ignore the catch rather than catch and throw the same thing.  Makes for cleaner code.

Comment: ... and it is preferrable to do so.

Comment: depends on the usecase. if you need to so something after a catch, but don't need to actually handle it, this is the way to go.

Comment: Since the question was just about "is it convention", you both are right : I'm going to edit

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the following...

```
public class PersonSaver {
    private final File file;

    public PersonSaver(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void save(List<Person> people) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            output.writeObject(people);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In any part of your code you can `throw` a throwable object, such as an Exception.

You should also state it in the method signature, letting the JVM know you'll handle that Exception in a caller's block.

Example:

```
public void save(List<Person> people) throws FileNotFoundException{
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            output.writeObject(people);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider if the calling code actually knows what to do with the specific exception. You have defined an API about saving a collection of `Person`. The calling code knows only about a `Person` and has no idea ideally where the save is done.
If you throw a lower level exception about the file not found you are leaking the abstraction and you won't be able to change the implementation easily if the calling code is starting to be aware of where things are saved.
The proper approach would be to throw an "business" exception like `PersonNotPersisted` or `PersonNotSaved` since this is something the calling code would understand and avoid the low level IO exceptions to the higher layer

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a method to throws an checkedexception you dont need to catch it or any of it subtypes:

```
public void save(List<Person> people) throws IOExcetion {
    try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        output.writeObject(people);
    }
}
```

If you want to handle the exception before you can also do like:

```
public void save(List<Person> people) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        output.writeObject(people);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The keyword 'throw' fires the exception to the caller.

Comment: *"If you declare a method to throws an checkedexception you dont need to catch it:"* ... Well, this isn't really true, is it.  For example, you've written an API that throws a custom checked exception `InvalidBusinessDateException`.  In your code, an `ArithmeticException` occurs when calculating a time stamp.  The best practice is to catch the arithmetic exception, and rethrow it as an `InvalidBusinessDateException` wrapped with the information the client needs to recover from the exception.

Comment: 'it' refers to the Exception you declared, other exceptions arent handled